# How to prevent symmetricds from sending outdated updates?

Tags: database, database-replication, symmetricds

I’m using **sync_on_incoming_batch** option
All nodes are offline

**Store1** updated price to 1.00

**Store2** updated price to 2.00

**Store1** sent 1.00 to **server**

**Server** sent 1.00 to **Store2** (now Store2 has 1.00 but on sym_data has 2.00 to send)
**Store2** sent 2.00 to **server**
**Server** sent 2.00 to **Store1**

In the end it was like this

**Store1** has 2.00
**Server** has 2.00
**Store2** has 1.00
Everyone should have 1.00, cause the Store1 made the update first.

I wanted a way disregard changes with dates prior to the
new data received...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the conflict resolution NEWER_WINS based on a column with a time stamp of the update could help in this scenario: https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.13/html/user-guide.html#_conflicts